# postgresql doesn't start with Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql

I'm facing a problem with postgresql, when I try to execute queries with psql I'm getting this kind of error:

**psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?**

the solution I have found on the web is to change access rights for this file:

**sudo chmod 777 /var/run/postgresql** and to restart postgresql by this command line **pg_ctl -D /home/mycomputer/var/postgres/ -l logfile restart**

After I log as postgres user **sudo su postgres** But for now I'm getting this error message:
**psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist**

I have searched on the web and didn't find the good way to solve this.

Could someone help me on this please. thank you in advance

Comment: By the way, I'm running the postgresql on Local

Answer (score 0):

Stop the database server and start it in single user mode.

Then you can query which users there are.

You'll have to figure out where the `postgres` executable is installed on your system, e.g. with `pg_config --bindir`. I'll assume `/path/to/postgres/bin` in the following.

- Become the PostgreSQL operatiing system user (usually `postgres`).
- Stop the PostgreSQL server with

```sh
    pg_ctl stop -D /home/mycomputer/var/postgres/ -m fast
```

- Start PostgreSQL in single user mode with

```sh
    /path/to/postgres/bin/postgres --single -D /home/mycomputer/var/postgres/ template1
```

- At the prompt, enter

  ```
  SELECT usename, usesuper FROM pg_user
  ```
- Leave the session and shut down the database by pressing `Ctrl+D`.

Now you know all users in that PostgreSQL cluster.

You can start the database server and use one of them to connect to the database.